# ERROR: NetworkId mismatch

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, swarm, networkid

I got stuck with the error:

> ERROR: NetworkId mismatch: 3 (!= 1100)

Running geth node with parameters:

```
geth --rpccorsdomain "*" --ipcapi "admin,eth,miner" --rpcapi "eth,web3" --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5 --etherbase "xxxxx(hidden)" --verbosity 3 --minerthreads 1 console
```

And then run swarm with:

```
$GOPATH/bin/swarm --bzzaccount 41bad198c4504045f3dfa54902e08384e9162b04 --datadir /home/ubuntu/.ethereum --ethapi /home/ubuntu/.ethereum/geth.ipc --verbosity 3 --maxpeers 5 --bzznetworkid 1100
```

After all I'm getting the logs:

> I0206 12:20:28.403510 errs/errors.go:86] [BZZ] ERROR: NetworkId mismatch: 3 (!= 1100)

Where could that error come from?

Comment: Have you considered to run geth with the `--datadir` flag? It looks like it uses the default existing testnet configuration somehow (which is ID #3).

Comment: @Anatolii: Did you find the solution for this? I have the same issue

Comment: For me it helped to add `--nodiscover` flag, but I was running only single node, so that was ok for me.